# how to pass utm_content to google play store and listen the broadcast

Tags: android, google-analytics

i am trying to use the google analytics in my app. But facing one weird issue.

describing my issue in details below:
i am having one app App1 which can handle specific intent, that intent is sending by my another app App2. but for the case when app1 is not installed on some device i want to launch the google play store with my app1 (if somebody wants to use functionality of app1 from app2), so that user can install the app1 and completes his/her scenario.

For this i am appending the

market://details?id=com.abc.xyz.app1&referrer=utm_source=com.abc.xyz.app2&utm_medium=SomeText&utm_content=content://*******(some values shared using content provider from app2 to app1. if app1 is installed i am sending all this info to app1 from app2 using content provider)

but on firing this intent google play is opening with blank screen.

the google playstore intent making and calling code is :

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
intent.setData(Uri.parse(market://details?id=com.abc.xyz.app1&referrer=utm_source=com.abc.xyz.app1&utm_medium=SomeText&utm_content=content://*******(some values shared using content provider));

startactivity(intent);

as written above after startactvity(intent) call from app2, i can see googleplay store but my app1 is not there . instead there is some blank screen in google play store app. seems play store is not getting the app1 id . I don't know why.

One more thing i observed, if i send the path using file:/// ... instead of content provider than every thing is working fine.

Comment: i solved the issue by removing the '#' character from it. it seems google play do not understand '#' character passed as utm_content

Answer (score 0):

It's not the answer but this what worked for me.

i solved the issue by removing the '#' character from it. it seems google play do not understand '#' character passed as utm_content.